# How can Display only current list item and hide others

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have register a widget with coding below

```
//Add our Widget Locations
function ourWidgetsMenu() {
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Menu for Courses',
    'id' => 'menuforcourses'
  ));
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'ourWidgetsMenu');
```

And added a category menu in it form WordPress admin and made it appear as coding below,

```
<div class="menuincoursepages">
  <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'menuforcourses' ); ?>
</div>
```

It's appearing on source code like below

```css
.menuincoursepages ul li {
  display: none;
}

.menuincoursepages .current-cat li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuincoursepages">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-3 current-cat"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/">Engineering</a> (11)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-358"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/aerospace-engineering/" >Aerospace Engineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-361"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/bioengineering/" >Bioengineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/civil-engineering/">Civil Engineering</a> (11)
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/">Marketing</a> (1)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/online-marketing/">Online Marketing</a> (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

But the thing is, I want to display list items only with class `current-cat` and it's sub-items and want to hide all other items and sub-items.

Till here, it's done with the help of Buwan (Thanks a lot)

Now I got another issue with this,

When I click on 'Civil Engineering' then code change as below,

```html
<div class="menuincoursepages">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-3 current-cat-parent current-cat-ancestor"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/">Engineering</a> (11)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-358"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/aerospace-engineering/" >Aerospace Engineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-361"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/bioengineering/" >Bioengineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-5 current-cat"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/civil-engineering/">Civil Engineering</a> (11)
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/">Marketing</a> (1)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/online-marketing/">Online Marketing</a> (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

and here I want to display all list-items which are under class 'current-cat-parent' and color red for class 'current-cat' which is for 'Civil Engineering' in this case

Let me know if this is also possible..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `:not()` selector here...

```css
.menuincoursepages li:not(.current-cat) {
  display: none;
}

.menuincoursepages .current-cat li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuincoursepages">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-3 current-cat"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/">Engineering</a> (11)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/civil-engineering/">Civil Engineering</a> (11)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/">Marketing</a> (1)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/online-marketing/">Online Marketing</a> (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

***Updated:*** You will need to change the css like below

```css
.menuincoursepages li {
  display: none;
}

.menuincoursepages li.current-cat,
.menuincoursepages li.current-cat-parent,
.menuincoursepages li.current-cat li,
.menuincoursepages li.current-cat-parent li {
  display: block;
}

.menuincoursepages .current-cat li,
.menuincoursepages .current-cat-parent li {
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.menuincoursepages li.current-cat {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menuincoursepages">
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-3 current-cat-parent current-cat-ancestor"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/">Engineering</a> (11)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-358"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/aerospace-engineering/">Aerospace Engineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-361"><a href="http://example.com/course-category/engineering/bioengineering/">Bioengineering</a> (1)</li>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-5 current-cat"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/engineering/civil-engineering/">Civil Engineering</a> (11)
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="cat-item cat-item-7"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/">Marketing</a> (1)
    <ul class='children'>
      <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a href="http://example.com/my-category/marketing/online-marketing/">Online Marketing</a> (1)
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Bhuwan,
It's working, I got another issue with this, which I just added, Can you please have a look for this? Thank you